# Photoshop : Taking existing Pixel art and Automatically creating individual layers

Tags: photoshop-scripting, automation, pixel, script, pixel-art

Right here is an interesting one. For a project I need each pixel of existing pixel art on an individual layer.

There are potentially hundreds of images so i cant just copy, paste to new layer for every pixel in every image

Is there a way it can be scripted to go though an image and save every pixel as a new layer???

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  Why are you trying to do this? What goal are you actually trying to achieve?   At the moment, your question reads like [an X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Your question has an [answer on superuser](https://superuser.com/a/425883). But I'm not sure it will help you achieve your goal. I only dared to test the script on a 32x32px image. That's 1024 layers. It took more than a minute to run the script. A 100x100px image would give you 10000 layers and I'm not sure how Photoshop handles that. And then you just have all those layers. I'm guessing this is for some kind of animation? Please explain in details what your end goal is. It might be easier to script the whole animation in one go than to manipulate all these layers manually.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. 

The target is to seperate each pixel to its own layer. Delete all the layers that are empty then export every layer as a PNG then use the PNG sequence inside of SparkAR to produce animations for Augmented Reality

If you have a better solution to this I am all ears as this is very much a learning curve for me